# PHP - Include file and execute code in it

Tags: php, php-include

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
        <div class="post">
            <h3 class="title"><?php $post["title"]; ?></h3>
            <p class="text"><?php $post["text"]; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to include it in other file and execute all the PHP code in it. How can i do it?

Comment: add include 'test.php'; put all the codes there and create a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include with absolute path :

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/yourdirectory/yourfile.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I was doing something else wrong, this wasnt the issue but it pointed me in correct directions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the include() function.

```
include("the file.php")
```

Comment: Try require() too